# One-Tap Sign In doesnt get connect to Google Cloud

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, intellij-idea, google-signin, google-one-tap

I need help with a problem I've been struggling with for 2 weeks. I have implemented Google One Tap SignIn functionality for my project. The backend works through IntelliJ and has been tested with Postman. However, the issue arises in Android Studio where, when I run the program on my actual device, the Google account login initiates but does not transition to the profile page. When using Android Studio's virtual emulators, the program doesn't respond to Google One Tap at all, meaning it doesn't even start the Google account login process. Here is the GitHub repository for the backend server and the Android Studio project.

Logcat (WITH VIRTUAL DEVICE)
com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbh could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).

Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0

```
  com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbh could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).
2024-02-22 17:20:03.402  6368-6368  Kirjautuminen           com.example.askolassakot             D  Kirjaudutaan...
2024-02-22 17:20:03.404  6368-6961  GoogleApiManager        com.example.askolassakot             W  com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbh could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).
2024-02-22 17:20:03.421  6368-6368  Kirjautuminen           com.example.askolassakot             D  Kirjaudutaan...
2024-02-22 17:20:04.108   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
2024-02-22 17:20:06.458  6368-6547  EGL_emulation           com.example.askolassakot             D  app_time_stats: avg=63.69ms min=2.67ms max=2386.63ms count=49
2024-02-22 17:20:06.693  6368-6392  le.askolassakot         com.example.askolassakot             I  Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
2024-02-22 17:20:10.503  6368-6547  EGL_emulation           com.example.askolassakot             D  app_time_stats: avg=277.68ms min=4.47ms max=3700.26ms count=14
2024-02-22 17:20:10.694  6368-6961  GoogleApiManager        com.example.askolassakot             W  com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbh could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).
2024-02-22 17:20:10.708  6368-6368  Kirjautuminen           com.example.askolassakot             D  Kirjaudutaan...
2024-02-22 17:20:10.709  6368-6961  GoogleApiManager        com.example.askolassakot             W  com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbh could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).
2024-02-22 17:20:10.774  6368-6368  Kirjautuminen           com.example.askolassakot             D  Kirjaudutaan...
2024-02-22 17:20:12.300   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
2024-02-22 17:20:13.806  6368-6547  EGL_emulation           com.example.askolassakot             D  app_time_stats: avg=60.68ms min=1.81ms max=2420.44ms count=45
2024-02-22 17:20:16.587   818-953   EGL_emulation           com.android.systemui                 D  app_time_stats: avg=16567.01ms min=16567.01ms max=16567.01ms count=1
2024-02-22 17:20:20.237   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
2024-02-22 17:20:28.173   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
2024-02-22 17:20:36.108   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
2024-02-22 17:20:44.301   811-811   wpa_supplicant          wpa_supplicant                       I  wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
```

Logcat (WITH OWN DEVICE)

https://github.com/mehturi/Askolassakot/blob/master/README.md (Very hard to read, sry)

https://github.com/mehturi/com.example.askolassaappserver

https://github.com/mehturi/Askolassakot

The following things have been tried:

1. Project has been rebuilt.
2. Cache has been cleared.
3. BASE_URL has been changed to the computer's IP address, and the phone's WLAN is connected to the same network as the computer. Same thing as localhost.
4. SHA-1 key is correctly set up in Google Cloud.
5. Logcat reports that there is no connection to the project every time the button is pressed.

Comment: update with full error or at least api exception number.

Comment: Logcat added to first post.

Comment: And there is no error.

Comment: And are you sure using correct debug SHA1 and release SHA1 on console and google-service.json?